# Arraylist Add "This" Class

Tags: java

I have a class that contains a Public Static Array List of the Same Object that the Class is, so the class is called Image and the Array list inside the Class is ArrayList. I have a method to store the object from within the Class, will a public  void method store the object in the ArrayList for all to use if I do list.add(this)? I'm a bit new so sorry if this sounds stupid or anything XD or doesn't make sense. Basically I want to make a storage system of Image Objects inside the Image Class, now initialised Image Objects can perform the function ImageExampleObject.addLib(), this public method addLib() performs list.add(this), list being the ArrayList of Image Objects. Will this work?

I didn't know how to search for a short sentence to describe what I want to find out, which is basically why I didn't find any question in this site that asks the same thing if you intend to say, someone already asked, why didn't you go look at that question, you should search next time. P:

Regards :)

Comment: I genuinely struggle to figure out what the question is.

Comment: It sounds like you have some code written - I recommend including any relevant code, and perhaps narrowing your question down. If it's a simple "will this work," I encourage you to try it and let us know if any problems pop up. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Yes. you can have a static ArrayList in your class that would store instances of this class. As to whether you should do it, that depends on what your code is trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "Yes it works".

Here is an implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Image {

    public static ArrayList<Image> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addLib() {
        list.add(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Image().addLib();
        new Image().addLib();
        new Image().addLib();

        for (Image image : list) {
            System.out.println("Image "+image+" is in store");
        }
    }

}
```

which outputs:

```
Image Image@3f8b995c is in store
Image Image@6601879b is in store
Image Image@6e6e056e is in store
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add `Item`s to the `ArrayList` in a constructor instead of a method.  Here is why:

The constructor of `Image` is where you probably should be calling `arrayList.add(this);`.  This makes it so `Image`s are added to the `static ArrayList` on instantiation.  That means you don't have to call a separate method to add them in.  This is a better guarantee that all `Image` instances will be accessible through that `ArrayList`.

```
public class Image{
    public static ArrayList<Image> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Image(){
        arrayList.add(this);
    }

    ...
}
```

If you only want select `Image`s stored then you would want slartidan's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use a static method to update the static list :

```
public class Image {

    public static ArrayList<Image> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void addLib(Image image) {
        Image.list.add(image);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Image.addLib (new Image());
        Image.addLib (new Image());
    }

}
```

I find it clearer to use static methods to manipulate static members.